# singleton class dlopen error for static function (not able to reproduce in sample code)!

Tags: c++, static, singleton, static-libraries

I'm not able to reprdouce the problem I have in my target application in some a nice & compact form to display, but I have written up the class definition I'm using for mysingleton that's causing me grief and I hope someone may be able to direct me to the solution.
Ok, the problem is, my application returns a runtime error that goes like:
`Error opening requested library (/path/to/./libcloudparc.sys.db_connector.so) dlopen() error: /path/to/./libcloudparc.sys.db_connector.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7db_pool8instance` where `db_pool` is my singleton class that looks like:

```
class someclA {
    public:
    someclA(int,int,int){}
    ~someclA(){}
};
class db_pool : public someclA {
    private:
    static db_pool *inst;
    db_pool(int &A,
              int &B,
              int &C): someclA(A,B,C){}
   public:
   static db_pool *getInstance(int &a,
                                 int &b,
                                 int &c) {
          if(!inst) {
             inst = new db_pool(a,b,c);

             inst->init(a,b,c);
            }
         return inst;
        }
        int init (int ,int,int);
};

int main (void) {
    int A=11;
    int B=22;
    int C=33;
    db_pool *inst = inst->getInstance(A,B,C);   
}
```

Why would I get a error as mentioned? Can anybody help me get ahead here?

Comment: Is db_pool::inst defined?

Comment: @immibis No, how/where do I define it best?

Comment: if it's c++17 you can just throw an inline before it (`static inline db_pool *inst;`).   Otherwise you just put the definition in a .cpp file (not a .h file) (`db_pool * db_pool::inst;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a variable in a class is `static`, it would belong to all instances of that class and not to one instance alone. So it would need to defined first. 
And you can have only one definition of that variable. So it has to be put in a source (not header) file outside of the class declaration.  You need to do something like this:

```
db_pool * db_pool::inst = nullptr; //for a start
```

Comment: That was i, I however still don't exactly understand why it has to be defined first: `static` is a variable at a fix place in memory, i'd expect it be present at all times as long as the program is running... why is this not the case?

Comment: class static variables have to be defined first and only then they begin to exist and only then they can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now!